Impact of Term Structure on Radius of Convergence: A Study of $\sum 3^n z^n$ vs. $\sum 3^n z^{2n} $
Consider two power series where the coefficients ( $a_n = 3^n$ ) are the same in both cases:

Series A: ( $\sum 3^n z^n $).

Series B: ( $\sum 3^n z^{2n}$ ).


My doubts:
1: Analyze and explain the difference in computing the radius of convergence ($ R $) for each series. Specifically: How does the presence of ($ z^n$ ) in Series $A$ and ( $z^{2n}$ ) in Series $B $ impact the radius of convergence, even though ($ a_n$ ) is the same in both cases?
2: When applying the formula  $\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ , should  $a_n$  be taken as  $3^n$  only, or as the entire term $ 3^n z^n$ $(or  3^n z^{2n}$  for Series B)? Note that if we take  $a_n = 3^n$  alone, the radius of convergence for both cases appears to be  $\frac{1}{3}$ , which seems contradictory to the structure of each series.
Thanks for the help: I am always confused here and so never feel confident to tackle such problems.

What if you were to work with [for Series B] the sum
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^n(z^2)^{n}$ $= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (3z^2)^n$ and then repeat what you used for Series (A)? Couldn't you conclude that this series converges iff the inequality $z^2 < \frac{1}{3}$ is true, or if the inequality $z < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is true? So the radius of convergence in Series (B) is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ whereas the radius of convergence in Series (A) is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Thanks for the response sir. $z^2 < \frac{1}{3}$ is true for the series B. So what would be the conclusion sir in context to my question.

For the series A  you have $a_n = 3^n$, for the series B, write $$3^0 z^0+3^1 z^2+3^2 z^4+3^3 z^6+\cdots$$
as
$$3^0 z^0+0\ z^1+3^1 z^2+0\ z^3+3^2 z^4+0\ z^5+3^3 z^6+\cdots$$
to see that $a_n = \begin{cases}3^{n/2}&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\0&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$

The thing is, the second series is actually in the form of $\sum a_n (z^2)^n$.  Thus the radius of convergence applies for $z^2$, not $z$. So we get $|z|^2<\frac{1}{3}$ or $|z|<\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

Here we've got, in the second series that the radius of convergence is,  by Cauchy-Hadamard: $\frac 1{\sqrt 3}.$
That's because the limit of the odd terms is $0,$ while that of the even ones is $\mid a_{2n}\mid^{\frac 1{2n}}=3^{\frac n{2n}}\rightarrow \sqrt 3.$
The first series is,  by the same criterion,  $\frac 13.$

Since on this site we go by length of the answer,  I understand the downvote.

I do not know who down voted your answer. People does without mentioning the reasons.

From first principles
Don't just blindly apply formulae—think about what you are doing and why.  The general idea here is that it is not too difficult to determine when a geometric series converges:
Observe that if
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n,
\qquad\text{then}\qquad
rS = \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^{n+1}. $$
It follows from this that
\begin{align*} (1-r)S
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n - \sum_{n=1}^{N} z^{r+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n - \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} r^n \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{N} r^n - \sum_{n=2}^{N} r^n - r^{N+1} \\
&= 1-r^{N+1}.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n = S = \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}. $$
Taking limits,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}. $$
The series converges (i.e. the limit exists) when $|r|<1$, and diverges when $|r|>1$.  This applies directly to the series in the question:

Series A is a geometric series with $r=3z$.  The above discussion then implies that Series A converges when
$$ |3z| = |r| < 1 \iff |z| < \frac{1}{3}.$$
In other words, the set of complex numbers $z$ for which Series A converges is a disk with radius $1/3$ centered at zero.  The series converges on a disk, and that disk has radius $1/3$, so it is reasonable to talk about a "radius of convergence," $R = 1/3$.

Series B is a geometric series with $r = 3z^2$.  The above discussion then implies that Series B converges when
$$ |3z^2| = |r| < 1 \iff |z| < \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}. $$
So this series has radius of convergence $\sqrt{1/3}$.


Where did the formula come from?
Very roughly speaking, suppose that a series is given by
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^n. $$
If the terms $a_nz^n$ are "approximately geometric", then the expectation is that the series should behave like a geometric series.
A little more precisely (but still with hands waving), the idea of terms being "approximately geometric" is that there is some $r>0$ ($r$ is for "ratio" here, as in the terms are geometric with common ratio $r$) such that
$$ a_n \approx r^n $$
when $n$ is "large enough".  If this is the case, then $a_nz^n \approx (rz)^n$, which is definitely geometric.  The first tempting idea is to observe that if $a_n \approx r^n$ for every $n$, then
$$ \sum a_nz^n \approx \sum r^n z^n, $$
which converges when $|rz| < 1$.  That is, the series will converge when
$$ 1 > |rz| = r |z| \iff |z| < \frac{1}{r}. $$
There difficulty here is that "$\approx$" is not really well-defined—what does this actually mean?  There are a number of different approaches to answering this question, but it turns out that a fairly reasonable thing to do is look at the limit of $a_n / r^n$.  Very roughly speaking, "$a_n \approx r^n$ for large $n$" means that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{r^n} = 1. $$
Unfortunately, this limit may not exist, even in fairly simple cases.  For example, suppose that
$$ \begin{cases}
a_{n} = 2^{n} & \text{if $n$ is even, and} \\
a_{n} = 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd.} \end{cases} $$
The work around for cases like this is to work with the limit superior (which will always exist) rather than the limit.  This gives rise to a general statement, in the direction of a theorem:

Suppose that the series $\sum a_n z^n$ has the property that
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{r^n} = 1
\iff \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|^{1/n}}{r} = 1
\iff \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = r. $$
Then $\sum a_n z^n$ will converge if and only if $\sum r^n z^n$ converges.  Observe that the latter series converges when
$$ |rz| < 1 \iff |z| < \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}},$$
and diverges when $|rz| > 1$.  That is, with
$$ R = \frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}}, $$
the series converges on the disk $|z|<R$, and diverges on the open complement of that disk (i.e. the series has radius of convergence $R$).

After all this work, the almost-theorem can be applied to the series in question:

For Series A, $a_n = 3^n$, so
$$ R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}} = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}. $$

Series B is a little more complicated, since
$$ a_n = \begin{cases} 3^{n/2} & \text{if $n$ is even, and} \\
0 & \text{if $n$ is odd.} \end{cases} $$
Taking the notation apart a bit,
$$ R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}
= \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{k\ge n} |a_k|^{1/k}}
= \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} (3^{\lceil n/2 \rceil})^{1/n}}
= \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} 3^{1/2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.
$$
(Note that, while it is not true that $\lceil n/2\rceil / n = 1/2$, it is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lceil n/2\rceil / n = 1/2$).


